# Derivative where x=a

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=x^3+3x+2$

Find the number(s) a such that the tangent lines to the graphs of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ at $x=a$ are the same.

So far I have come up with:

$f'(x)=3(x^2+1)$

And when I graph both these functions out on my calculator the only point I am finding where $x=a$ is at $1$ (which could be incorrect as it is hard to tell exact points using only graphs).

First is this correct? and second is there a better way of coming to that conclusion rather than graphing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For "the tangent lines to the graphs of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ at $x=a$ are the same" to be true, you need two things:

1. The tangent lines to pass through the points $\left( a, f(a)\right)$ and $\left( a, f'(a)\right)$ which, assuming the tangents are not vertical, requires $ f(a)= f'(a) $
2. The tangent lines to have the same gradient which, assuming the tangents are not vertical, requires $ f'(a)= f''(a) $

The tangent lines are not vertical $-$ you can check $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ $-$ so these will give you two equations to solve: one a cubic and the other a quadratic.

Solve one of them and see which of its solutions satisfy the other.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: What is the definition of the tangent to a curve at point?

You are trying to find the equivalence of the *tangent lines*, not the functions themselves.